# Same remainders of a sequence

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math

> Show that for the sequence $x_{1}=9$ and $x_{n+1} = 9^{x_{n}}$ the remainders for the third and fourth term are equal when divided by $100$. Determine this remainder.

So the second term seems to be $x_{2}=9^9$ and therefore the third and fourth $x_{3}=9^{9^9}, x_{4}=9^{9^{9^9}}$.

Is there some exponent rule we need to apply here or what would be the way to go about this?

Comment: Familiar with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_order ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is to find $\operatorname{ord}_{100}(9)$, say $m$ and show that $x_2\equiv x_3\pmod m$.
As $\gcd(4,25)=1,\,100=4\cdot 25$ it suffices to find $m=\operatorname{ord}_{25}(9)$ as $9\equiv 1\pmod 4$ so $9^m\equiv 1\pmod {100}\Leftrightarrow 9^m\equiv 1\pmod {25}$ by Chinese Remainder Theorem.
So, how to proceed with pen and paper, as OP is tageg 'contest-math':
As $m|\varphi(25)=20$ so we have only to test positive divisors of $20$, namely $1,2,4,5,10,20$, alone to say $9^{\varphi(25)}\equiv 1\pmod{25}$ by little Fermat's Theorem and $9\not\equiv 1\pmod{25}$, so let's start with $2$:
$9^2=81\equiv 6\pmod{25}$
$9^4=(9^2)^2\equiv 6^2\equiv 11\pmod{25}$
$9^5=9\cdot 9^4\equiv 9\cdot 11\equiv -1\pmod{25}$, and finally
$9^{10}=(9^5)^2\equiv (-1)^2\equiv 1\pmod{25}$, so [$m=10$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=MultiplicativeOrder%5B9%2C+25%5D).

Now $x_2=9^9\equiv 9\pmod{10}$, so $9^{x_2}\equiv 9^9\pmod{100}$ $\Rightarrow 9^{x_2}\equiv 9^9\pmod{10}$ hence the desired result.

Now we find $9^9\pmod{100}$ like $(9^3)^3$ or $9((9^2)^2)^2$ -- 4 multiplications either way (I'll omit the details). $9^9\equiv 89\pmod{100}$

Answer (score 0):

$$x_{3}=9^{(9^9)}$$
$$x_3 \equiv 1^{(9^9)} \equiv1 \pmod 4$$
By euler's theorem,
$$9^{\phi(25)} \equiv1 \pmod{25} \implies 9^{20k} \equiv1 \pmod{25}$$ 
for some positive integer $k$ and $$9^{\phi(20)} \equiv1 \pmod{20} \implies 9^9 \equiv9 \pmod{20} \implies 9^9 =20k+9$$
$$\implies x_3 \equiv 9^{20k+9} \equiv9^{20k} \cdot9^9 \equiv 1\cdot9^9 \equiv3^{18}\pmod{25}$$
$$\implies 9x_3 \equiv3^{20} \equiv3^{\phi(25)} \equiv1 \pmod{25} \implies 3x_3 \equiv17 \equiv 42\pmod{25}$$
$$\implies x_3 \equiv 14 \pmod{25}$$
Now, 
$$x_3 \equiv1 \pmod{4} \implies x_3=4m+1$$
$$4m+1 \equiv14 \pmod{25} \implies4m \equiv13 \equiv88 \pmod{25} \implies m \equiv22\pmod{25}$$ $$\implies m=25n+22 \implies x_3 =4(25n+22)+1=100n+89 \equiv89 \pmod{100}$$